# Cannot customize PrimeNG Quill Editor in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I am using [PrimeNG Editor (based on Quill](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/editor) in an Angular 7 project and I want to customize the toolbar. Although I have tried some of the configuration options on HTML and JavaScript side, the only thing I managed to update is `placeholder` property via HTML side. Here is my approach (I defined Editor as a custom control):

***#FormComponent.ts:***

```
public controlDescription = new ControlEditor({
    key: 'Description',
    label: 'Description',
    required: true
});

this.controls = [this.controlDescription, ... ];
```

***#FormComponent.html:***

```
<div comp-dynamic-control [form]="form" [control]="controlDescription"></div>
```

***#ControlEditor.html:***

```
<p-editor [formControlName]="control.key" placeholder='Compose text...'></p-editor>
```

Please note that I also tried to use Editor directly (without our Custom Editor) using the following code in **FormComponent.html** but there is no editor seems on the page despite adding **import {EditorModule} from 'primeng/editor';** to the ControlEditor.ts file. ANy idea?

```
<p-editor formControlName="description" [style]="{'height':'320px'}"></p-editor>
```

Comment: import EditorModule in your app.module.ts file.

Comment: Thanks, but I already import this to the app.module and my component.ts file (FormComponent.ts). Any idea?

Comment: Any help please?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm using Angular 9 and for me the customization only worked when i provided the `formats` property with a `string array` of all the desired formats (buttons) and next to that i needed to add the buttons in the html page as well. The buttons needed to be enclosed within `p-header`  tags and the `p-header` tags needed to be between the `p-editor` tags like so:

```
<p-editor [(ngModel)]="value" [style]="{'height':'100px'}" formats="formats">
    <p-header>
       <span class="ql-formats">
        <button class="ql-bold" aria-label="Bold"></button>
        <button class="ql-italic" aria-label="Italic"></button>
       </span>
    </p-header>
</p-editor>
```

The `bold` and `italic` buttons will only appear when i also define them in a string array in the typescript page like so:

```
formats: string[] = ['bold', 'italic'];
```

Here are all the other options: https://quilljs.com/docs/formats/

don't forget to add `formats="formats"` to the first `p-editor` tag

Comment: I am getting a similar issue in angular 9 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61889006/primeng-quill-editor-custom-font-size-setting-issue-with-angular-9, can you please look?

Answer (score -1):

You need to import the Editor module in your Module level, not a component level ts file.

**App.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import {EditorModule} from 'primeng/editor';


@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, EditorModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I already import this to the app.module and my component.ts file (FormComponent.ts). I also tried to add as shown below but it does not make any sense as it had already been added to the shared module). Any idea?

Comment: please do not import multiple times. remove from the component.ts file